# reset button in form doesn't reset selection to first element because of selected keyword in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reset, forms, html-select

I have a reset button in a form

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

and some selections

```
<select>
<option value="0">A</option>
<option value="10" selected="selected">B</option>
</select>
```

If I click on reset nothing happens. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rucC6/1/) is an example.

**Edit:**
I thought that the reset button will reset to the first value of a selection list. It seems that was a missunderstanding of my side. I want to reset to the first element of a selection.

So is the only way to create a reset function in Javascript? What if the user has turned off Javascript?

Comment: Then you are SOL. -You COULD make the reset a submit button that requested a new form with the selected on item 0

Comment: @testing, your fiddle works for me on Firefox 10 (selecting another option then clicking `Reset` restores `product a` as the selected value). What browser are you using?

Comment: What is SOL? I'm using Firefox 11, Chrome 17, IE 9 ... I've bad experiences with multiple submit buttons, because `this.form.submit();` doesn't work anymore. Product a is selected per default. When the user clicks on Reset it should show "-none-".

Comment: @testing, this is not the way `reset` buttons work. The value that was initially selected when the page loaded will be restored, not the first value of the list.

Comment: So how can I reset to the first value of the list?

Comment: Without scripting, you can't, unless you modify your markup so the first value of the list is the one selected when the page is loaded.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: The easiest way is to set a link on the page (so page is reloaded and the first element is set).

Answer (score 3):

Force value to nothing of all inputs, select, etc...

```
$("#filter_form").find("select, input, checkbox").val("");
```

Answer (score 2):

When I click on reset button, form reset in defaults. It's working in your example (option 10 is default).